# Will homosexuality be granted in Heaven for those who have been patient?

Tags: jannah, homosexuality

I'm a woman who happened to be one of those who are born attracted to their same gender. But, I'm a strong follower of islam and I love Allah a lot! Therefore I suppress all my desires for the sake of god, and I know for a fact that I will never allow myself to commit a sin involving homosexuality.
Yet, everyone ends up loving someone, and I'm not an exception. I happened to (secretly) really love this one person, but I will never pursue it no matter what.
What I am wondering about is, our prophet (pbuh) said that in heaven everyone will be married to the one he truly loves, and nothing is prohibited. If I was patient for my whole life and kept on doing right deeds, then am I able to end up with that person in heaven? Even though it's homosexual?

Comment: would someone go to ' jannah' if he wishes to go jannah for doing something haram

Comment: There's no definite answer to this question: first you have to assume you enter heaven in your earthly body, based on logic and Ahadith you don't. If you don't, then you have to assume you'll have the same exact desires you have here, once again, an assumption. There's no definite answer, Allah Knows Best.

Comment: "Gardens of perpetual residence, which they will enter, beneath which rivers flow. They will have therein whatever they wish. Thus does Allah reward the righteous". [Quran translation, 16:31] *** But after struggling on Earth and getting into Paradise, insha Allah, will you have the same desire?

Answer (score 3):

Most scholars agree that if you only *wish* and don't *commit* this sin, you will not be punished on the day of judgement. Because you follow what is mentioned in this verse:

> وَذَرُوا ظَاهِرَ الْإِثْمِ وَبَاطِنَهُ
>   And leave what is outward (dhahir) of sin and what is in depth (batin) thereof [6:120]

An outward (dhahir) sin means: You can see it's a sin, it's obvious that it's bad, you don't wish to commit it and nobody needs to tell you that you shouldn't commit it.

A profound / in depth sin (batin) means: You don't '*see*' it's a sin, but you know it, because Quran and prophet told you. You understand it with reason, but not with heart. You might even desire it, but you know it's wrong.

So every deed has an outward appearance (appearance of this world) and an inside/profound appearance (otherwordly appearance). The otherwordly appearance of a sin is fire, which we can't see in this life, but will see in the next.

> They know only the outside appearance (dhahir) of the life of the world, and they are heedless of the Hereafter. [30:7]

We only see the outside appearance of a sin, like a sin involving homosexuality. Though most people don't desire it, some do. But this is only because we all cannot see the true (otherwordly, deeper, batin) appearance of this sin.

If you could see it, you wouldn't have any desire to come close to it. Maybe Allah will grant you to 'see' the reality of this sin, the otherwordly appearance of this sin, even in this life. 
Definetly in the hereafter we will all see the reality of our deeds and wishes. Ugly and beauty creatures will follow us wherever we go. The more good deeds we've done, the more beauty and sweet smelling creatures will be close to us. The more sins we've commited, the more ugly and foul-smelling creatures will follow us. This is based on Ahadith.

So why would someone wish to be close to an ugly creature? Because this is what the sin is.

I hope I could give at least part of an answer to your question.

What we muslims all really should want and wish is to be close to Allah (*meet his Lord*, 18:110) and to *be in the proximity of the King all-powerful* (54:55), not only the garden, fruits, rivers and partners.
Like the prophets who only wished to be close to Allah (t.).

Comment: **<comments deleted>** We are not here to judge whether or not homosexuality is "natural" or not. Please keep posts and comments limited to the topic of Islam, not debating controversial points.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the description of Paradise, which the righteous are promised, wherein are ... rivers of wine delicious to those who drink..." (Surah Muhammad, 47:15)

There are rivers of alcohol in Paradise. Wine is haraam on Earth.

Thus, it could be that things forbidden on Earth may be granted in Heaven.

Comment: Wasnt alcohol permissible to the earlier  Ummahs before Islam?

Comment: @Ahmed I don't understand the point you're making. If something was permissible before Islam, it doesn't mean Islam permits it. But yes, there was a period where Islam discouraged alcohol but did not outright forbid it.

Comment: Apologies. I should have been more elaborate in my comment. When you made the comparison between paradise and earth, it was my assumption that by saying 'Earth' you imply it was never permissible on this planet. Hence,the query.

Comment: "No bad effect is there in it, nor from it will they be intoxicated. (37:47)" Wine in the hereafter is fundamentally different from wine on Earth. You cannot say the same thing about other sins.

Comment: Good find, @TheZ

Answer (score 0):

It's likely this question is not definitely answerable, as most specific details about heaven have not been revealed.  Moreover, heaven is probably incomprehensible to humans:

> Allah said, "I have prepared for My righteous slaves (such excellent things) as no eye has ever seen, nor an ear has ever heard nor a human heart can ever think of."
> <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 7498](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/123)</sub>

Consequently, answers to *what will heaven be like?* are probably far less accurate than answers to *what will the world be like in 100 years?* (except for what was revealed by Allah).

Nevertheless, to attempt to answer the question:

#### Maybe...

The Qur'an says:

> Circulated among them will be plates and vessels of gold. And **therein is whatever the souls desire and [what] delights the eyes**, and you will abide therein eternally.
> <sub>[Qur'an 43:71](https://quran.com/43/71)</sub>

There may be exceptions to this (e.g., if someone desires something against Allah's will), or Allah may have instead designed heaven so that these exceptions do not arise.

The Qur'an also talks about drinking non-intoxicating wine in heaven ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=1810)), e.g.:

> They will exchange with one another a cup [of wine] wherein [results] no ill speech or commission of sin.
> <sub>[Qur'an 52:23](https://quran.com/52/23)</sub>

So the worldly problems with wine do not apply to the form of wine available in heaven.  It's thus plausible that the worldly problems with homosexuality analogously don't apply in heaven.

However, drinking wine is not considered wholly bad (*...great sin and [yet, some] benefit...* [Qur'an 2:219](https://quran.com/2/219)), which distinguishes it from homosexuality.  Moreover, non-alcoholic wine is sometimes considered halal by scholars (e.g. *...any drink that does not cause intoxication ... is not deemed to be haraam...* [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/148690)).  Thus, the applicability of the "wine in heaven" analogy is questionable.

#### Maybe not...

It's also plausible that homosexuality does not take place in heaven.  This seems logical, since homosexuality is described in the Qur'an as "transgressing":

> And leave what your Lord has created for you as mates? But you are a people transgressing.
> <sub>[Qur'an 26:166](https://quran.com/26/166)</sub>

In this context, presumably homosexual interests will become something else, such as towards straight intercourse ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=85663)), or something else.

(At a philosophical level, such a radical change in a person's interests would be perceived as a radical change in that person.  It raises the question: *who is actually entering heaven?*  This gets too far away from the posed question.)